# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in zeppelin on running spark code for creating dataframe using SQL DB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have zeppelin 0.8.2 installed and on running code:

```
%spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._    
val df_abc = spark.table("db_sandbox.sandbox_table")
```

I am getting error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.sendBaseOneway(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/thrift/TBase;)V
  at com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.send_shutdown(FacebookService.java:436)
  at com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.shutdown(FacebookService.java:430)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.close(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:619)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:154)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.close(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2562)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.close(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.close(Hive.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:331)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:318)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:294)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:221)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:220)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:356)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:216)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.databaseExists(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:238)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.isRunningDirectlyOnFiles(Analyzer.scala:750)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:683)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:715)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:708)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:708)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.table(SparkSession.scala:637)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.table(SparkSession.scala:633)
```

Spark installed on CDH 6.3.3 with version 2.4.0 which has dependency jars libthrift-0.9.3-1 & libfb-0.9.3 installed but still the NoSuchMethod Error can be seen.

Could anyone please assist me for this issue.

Comment: Try adding libthrift-0.9.3 jar and restart the Spark Interpreter should fix the issue.

Comment: It's already added in spark jars. Do I have to do something different than that?